# PostgreSQL drops table after program starts

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

My goal is basically create a very simple backend application with postgresql, and spring boot. Everytime I run my program I need to insert datas into my database table, because for some reason it does not save permanently. Is this a normal behaviour? To be frank im pretty new to postgresql and spring boot, therefore im sorry if the answer to this question is obvious.

My configuration file:

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(BlogpostRepository blogrep, CategoryRepository catrep){
        return args -> {

            blogPost blog1=new blogPost(1,"asd","asd","asd","asd");
            blogPost blog2=new blogPost(2,"asd2","asd2","asd2","asd2");

            Category cat1=new Category(1,"titles1");
            Category cat2=new Category(2,"titles2");
            Category cat3=new Category(3,"titles3");


            blogrep.saveAll(
                    List.of(blog1,blog2)
            );

            catrep.saveAll(
                    List.of(cat1,cat2,cat3)

                    );
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a missing `commit` somewhere.

Comment: No, this isn't normal behavior unless you delete everything somewhere/drop the tables/or if you're working with an in-memory database in stead of with postgres.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name instead or after the save all, should I do a repository.commit? Or something like that. Could you elaborate pls? Can I do a commit in spring boot?

Comment: @BalázsPatai Enable Hibernate SQL logging. And check the SQL queries as the first step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this problem was in the `application.properties`
file. From create and drop I changed it to:

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`